# running GL ES 2.0 code under Linux ( no Android no iOS )

Tags: glsl, opengl-es2, linux

I need to code OpenGL ES 2.0 bits and i would like to do this and run the programs on my desktop for practical reasons.

Now, i already have tried the official GLES SDK from ATI for my videocard but it not even runs the examples that comes with the SDK itself, i'm not looking for performance here, even a software based rendering pipeline could be enough, i just need full support for GLES 2.0 and GLSL to code and run GL stuff.

There is a reliable solution for this under Ubuntu Linux ?

Answer (score 2):

I use JOGL, it uses every OpenGL profile you can think of. You can find it at Jogamp.org.